# NSURLConnection return bad cacheData

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

In my AppDelegate method I create cache

```
NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:(10 * 1024 * 1024) diskCapacity:(100 * 1024 * 1024) diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
```

I have next NSURLConnection class

```
@implementation ImageDownloader {
    NSURLConnection *serverConnection;
    NSMutableData *imageData;
}

- (void)startDownloading
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.link] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:10];
    imageData = [NSMutableData new];
    serverConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
    [serverConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [serverConnection start];
}

- (void)cancelDownloading
{
    [serverConnection cancel];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [imageData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    [self sendDelegateImage:image];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self sendDelegateImage:nil];
}

- (void)sendDelegateImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    [self.delegate imageDownloader:self didLoadAtIndexPath:self.indexPath image:image];
}

@end
```

I use it when my tableView cells appears. In first load all good, and in first use of cache all good, but when I load my tableView in third time, cache data returned very small, and I have not image. Why NSURLConnection return bad cached data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try implementing `connection:didReceiveResponse:`

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {
        self.dataReceived = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
```

From the docs:

> In rare cases, for example in the case of an HTTP load where the
>   content type of the load data is multipart/x-mixed-replace, the
>   delegate will receive more than one connection:didReceiveResponse:
>   message. In the event this occurs, delegates should discard all data
>   previously delivered by connection:didReceiveData:, and should be
>   prepared to handle the, potentially different, MIME type reported by
>   the newly reported URL response.

Edit:
Also, just noticed you are using `[NSMutableData new]` to initialise your data; you should be using `[NSMutableData alloc] init]`.